# Strange "IDE" folder on my D: drive

Tags: windows-10, user-folders

I've recently noticed that there is a folder Ididn't create on my `D:` drive. It's been there since I recently installed Windows 10 Pro on this machine.
On this path: `D:\IDE\Common7\IDE\es\` there are 8 files named:

```
microsoft.visualstudio.vspsqlenum.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspsmo.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspesmoenum.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspconnectioninfo.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspservicebrokerenum.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspgridcontrol.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspregsvrenum.resources.dll
microsoft.visualstudio.vspwmienum.resources.dll
```

What are those files, and, can I delete them?

Comment: did you install Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: IDE = Integrated Development Environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those files are bundled with Visual Studio (Libraries not Bundleware) you can delete them. Unless you use Visual Studio